# Ruby undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, nagios

I'm trying to make nagios check for BBU (Battery Backup Unit), I have this ruby script called `check_bbu`

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'json'

output = %x{/usr/sbin/storcli /c0/bbu show j}

begin
        j = JSON.parse(output)
        result = j["Controllers"][0]["Command Status"]["Status"]
        status = j["Controllers"][0]["Response Data"]["BBU_Info"][0]["State"]
rescue Exception => e
        puts "CRITICAL: error reading BBU status: #{e}"
        exit 2
end

if result != 'Success'
        puts "CRITICAL: command not successful, result: #{result}"
        exit 2
end

if status != 'Optimal'
        puts "CRITICAL: BBU not optimal, status is #{status}"
        exit 2
end

puts "OK: BBU is optimal"
```

But when I run this plugin I'm getting following error,

```
$ ./check_nrpe -u -t 30 -H foo.example.com -c check_bbu
CRITICAL: error reading BBU status: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong in this ?

Comment: can you add what you get in `j` ?
This error told you that some data by one of this keys `[0] or ["Command Status"] or ["Response Data"] or ["BBU_Info"] or [0]` return nil, so next key can't be used for nil

Comment: output = %x{/usr/sbin/storcli /c0/bbu show j}

p JSON.parse(output)

Comment: And I answered you just write `puts JSON.parse(output)` it will return what you get in `j`

Comment: Also, what version of Ruby do you use?

Comment: @AlexGolubenko I'm using ruby 1.8.7

Comment: @AlexGolubenko I'm getting some kinda JSON output like this, `{"Controllers"=>[{"Command Status"=>{"Controller"=>0, "Status"=>"Failure", "Description"=>"None", "Detailed Status"=>[{"Ctrl"=>0, "Status"=>"Failed", "Property"=>"-", "ErrMsg"=>"use /cx/cv", "ErrCd"=>1001}]}}]}
CRITICAL: error reading BBU status: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: So, you can see that `["Controllers"][0]` doesn't return `hash` with `key` named `"Response Data"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example to my comment, lets imagine that we have correct JSON:

```
j = {"Controllers" => [{"Comand Status" => {"status" => 'ok'}}]}
=> {"Controllers"=>[{"Comand Status"=>{"status"=>"ok"}}]}
```

so by typing your first line, it's should return correct result:

```
> j["Controllers"][0]["Comand Status"]["status"]
=> "ok"
```

But also you can get wrong JSON, for example:

```
j_e = {"Controllers" => []}
```

so now it's return error:

```
>j_e["Controllers"][0]["Comand Status"]["status"]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

to solve it, you can use something like:

```
def try data, keys # there we take arguments: data == j, and keys == array with keys
  return data if data.nil? # there we check: if data, that we send == nil, for example j = nil, array = ['first', etc..] we should stop this method and return nil as result
  value = data[keys.shift] # on this line we try to get some data from j ##keys.shift will delete first element from array that we send to this method and return as `key` for `data`, for example data['Controllers'] so keys now will looks like: [0, 'Comand Status', 'status']
  unless keys.empty? #on this line we check if on the pred line we was used the last key and keys now looks like: [] we: *return value and if it's not empty we just **call this method 1 more time
    try(value, keys) #**value = [{"Comand Status" => {"status" => 'ok'}}] and keys = [0, 'Comand Status', 'status']
  else
    value #*nil or value
  end
end



j = {"Controllers"=>[{"Comand Status"=>{"status"=>"ok"}}]}
try(j, ['Controllers', 0, 'Comand Status', 'status'])
>'ok'
try j, ['Controllers', 1, 'Comand Status', 'status']
> nil
```

in you code this should looks like:

```
require 'json'

def try data, keys
  return data if data.nil?
  value = data[keys.shift]  
  unless keys.empty?
    try(value, keys)
  else
    value
  end
end


output = %x{/usr/sbin/storcli /c0/bbu show j}
begin
  j = JSON.parse(output)
  result = try(j, ["Controllers", 0, "Command Status", "Status"])
  status = try(j, ["Controllers", 0, "Response Data", "BBU_Info", 0, "State"])
rescue Exception => e
  puts "CRITICAL: error reading BBU status: #{e}"
  exit 2
end

if result != 'Success'
  puts "CRITICAL: command not successful, result: #{result}"
  exit 2
end

if status != 'Optimal'
  puts "CRITICAL: BBU not optimal, status is #{status}"
  exit 2
end

puts "OK: BBU is optimal"
```

Also, for **Ruby 2.3.0+**

it's much easier, just:

```
j.dig("Controllers", 0, "Comand Status", "status")
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me a lot. Could you please explain what is that piece of code, how it's working from `def try ... end` ?

Comment: @Rahul I think, you can add new Question, It is not convenient to answer in the comments

Comment: can you join me on chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126109/discussion-between-rahul-and-alex-golubenko ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems your code break at

```
j = JSON.parse(output)
result = j["Controllers"][0]["Command Status"]["Status"]
status = j["Controllers"][0]["Response Data"]["BBU_Info"][0]["State"]
```

you should check which line

1. `j == nil`, and your want `j["Controllers"]`
2. `result = j["Controllers"][0]["Command Status"]["Status"]`
3. `status = j["Controllers"][0]["Response Data"]["BBU_Info"][0]["State"]`

cause `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` by display `j` value first, and make sure json format match your code.

```
j = JSON.parse(output)
p j # display value
```

update:

your json format should match your code, otherwise it will raise error.

for example:

```
{
  "Controllers": [
    {
      "Commandddd Status": { # format not match
        "Status": "success"
      }
    }
  ]
}

# code and json format not match
j["Controllers"][0]["Command Status"] # nil

j["Controllers"][0]["Command Status"]["Status"]
=> nil["Status"] #  boom!
```

Comment: can you please elaborate little bit, I still don't understand what to check for

Comment: Hi @Rahul, I add an unmatched json example for demo why the error occur.

Comment: yep, I understood this very well.